# Does OpenTelemetry work for non-API services?

Tags: python, open-telemetry

I'm trying to implement openTelemetry in a service, but it's not an API, so there's no route to trace. It's just a worker app that manages some queues and sends/saves data.
I already did it in some APIs, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to bind openTelemetry features to my application.

My app starts with:

```
consumer = SQSConsumer()
consumer_thread = Thread(target=consumer.start_consume)  
consumer_thread.start()
```

and all the work is made by other classes called in the `start_consume` method.

So there wil be no HTTP requests to trace. I would like to trace this thread, how many messages I'm receiving and timestamps to process it, but OpenTelemetry tutorials for Python are not clear about how to perform this in a non-API service.

I'm wondering if is even a good ideia to use OpenTelemetry in this context. Did anyone do this before?

I tried to implement just like my other APIs, using OpenTelemetry examples. For HTTP APIs it works like a charm:

```
otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=config('OPTL_ENDPOINT'))
span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter)

trace.set_tracer_provider(
    TracerProvider(resource=Resource.create({"service.name": config('OPTL_SERVICE_NAME')}))
)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)
```

and instruments the main app:

`FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(my-app)`

For my APIs, receiving HTTP requests, I have several spans and metrics working just fine.

Comment: I use it in command line scripts so yes, it works. Automatic instrumentation will tell you what eg SQLAlchemy or `requests` do. To make real sense of this though, even with APIs, you'll have to decide which operations are significant in your code and mark them, so you can see what operation caused what, what was skipped etc

Comment: Doe you mean something like Martin described in https://www.honeycomb.io/blog/understanding-distributed-tracing-message-bus when you say non-API services? That is, queues, buses, etc.?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHausenblas! That's related but not quite. I don't really need to pass those traces to another system, except for the OpenTelemetry collector, which I have already working. What I'm trying to achieve is only add that generic automatic mode of OpenTelemetry (or something like) to a regular simple python app, which is not an API.
How do I add instrumentation to that? For instance, for APIs I use `FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(my-app)` to bind the app to OT tracing. That's what I don't get when working with non API services, in this case I don't have an object `app` to bind.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos! So you launch your app through command line? Would you give some example of that? With my APIs I just trace generic data from requests and exceptions by adding the trace to the FastAPI app object, in the main module, so the whole API is already instrumented.
In this case though, I don't have an app to bind with OpenTelemetry.
Would you give some example of your instrumentation and command line?

Answer (score 0):

So, I implemented it and returned to share it with anyone who might have the same question. Short answer: yes, it does.

We need to instrument every package you want to trace. In my case, pymongo, sqlalchemy and botocore (boto3 low level module). My confusion is that I had learned only the instrumentation for requests of a FastAPI service, therefore, there was only one framework to trace.

OpenTelemetry's docs and examples are quite fare. But to maintain a trace throughout my entire app, I had to create an unique tracer object to be used everywhere.

```
# opentelemetry.py module

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor

__otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint=config('OPTL_ENDPOINT'), insecure=True)
__span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(__otlp_exporter)

trace.set_tracer_provider(
    TracerProvider(resource=Resource.create({"service.name": config('OPTL_SERVICE_NAME')}))
)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(__span_processor)

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
```

Then, I can simply import it and maintain the same context for every message received, considering my app is an AWS SQS message handler:

```
from app.telemetry.open_telemetry import tracer
from opentelemetry.context import get_current

class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls):
        with tracer.start_as_current_span('new_span', get_current()) as current_span:
    # ..... my code.....
```

Hope this helps anyone.